# Finding list of objects that contain full or just part of searched string

Tags: c#

I've a list of paragraphs. Each paragagraph can contain Text. I'm trying to search for a string that may be as whole within a single paragraph, or spread across multiple paragraphs with as bad case where each letter is different paragraph.

```cs
public List<WordParagraph> FindText(string text) {
    List<WordParagraph> list = new List<WordParagraph>();
    var found = false;
    Paragraph currentParagraph = null;
    foreach (var paragraph in this.Paragraphs) {
        //if (currentParagraph == null) {
        //    currentParagraph = paragraph._paragraph;
        //} else {
        //    if (currentParagraph != paragraph._paragraph) {
        //        found = false;
        //    }
        //}
        // paragraph.Text
        // logic missing to find text that can start within some paragraph.Text, but
        // can span across multiple paragraphs
        // for example searching for text "This Is MyTest" within 4 paragraphs that
        // may be written like
        // paragraph.Text = "Thi"
        // paragraph.Text = "s Is"
        // paragraph.Text = " MyTes"
        // paragraph.Text = "t"
    }
    return list;
}
```

I've tried some logic around foreach char in text, and nested loop over text from the paragraph.text but the logic was failing me.

To give you a bit of background. Consider a Word Document that has a single sentence - one long sentence but each word, or even letter is formatted differently - different font size, bold, underline or whatever. It looks like this:

[image]

Now what Word actually saved in the file is a single paragraph, but each paragraph has multiple "runs". The run contains a Text element. Each text element contains the text that you see in Word, but due to formatting of possibly even each word it can be split into many many small Text properties.

[image]

Now in my example, I've simplified the logic and for me, each "run" is a paragraph with a text. So List of WordParagraphs is a list of runs within Screenshot you see.

Now I need to find a string "I have that" from the whole sentence you see in word. That means I need to go thru all paragraphs, find the first letter that matches and then check if next letter matches as well, if not I need to start again.

My brain is having hard time to grasp this logic in code.

Comment: Have you used `string.Contains()`? It doesn't see very useful to search by individual letter. Can you give a full input example, such as with `text` and `this.Paragraphs`? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Let's say I have a Text that is "This is very very long string". Each word or even single letter can be stored as part of paragraph. So in worst case scenario I can have 1st paragraph having letter T, second paragraph having letter h and so on. And lets say I search for "very long" string. I need to know now which paragraphs out of possibly even 50 contain it fully or partially.

Comment: Please post example `this.Paragraphs` values. I don't understand the benefit of searching for a word one letter at a time where each letter is in a different paragraph.

Comment: You already have all the text loaded up why not just merge and do a single contains ?

Comment: Can you please show WordParagraph class file?

Comment: I would join all the paragraphs into one string. Search the position of the search text and then add up the paragraph lengths until you get a position within the search text. This gives you the first paragraph. Then continue adding paragraph lengths until it spans the whole search text to get the succeeding paragraphs.

Comment: I assume the text needs to be in order? So if the string is `test` then it will match paragraphs `["ThE", "fox", "SiTs"]` but not `["ThE", "fox", "baTS"]`?

Comment: Such a search is going to be very inefficient.

Comment: Does the whole of the searched for text *have* to appear in the paragraphs, or could it be that only part of the text has to appear?  If it's the latter, then the answer is almost certainly **true**.

Comment: The text needs to be in order. It can start in the middle of first 2nd paragraph text property and end on 5th but it has to be continued.

Comment: I've updated question with some background to better understand logic.

Comment: Olivier has some good advice. Ignore the fact that you have different object, do you know what logic you'd use if your input was a single string with no Microsoft Word formatting syntax?

Comment: I guess I could join the string, use indexof, track with dictionary when each paragraph starts/ends, but i guess I thought since I am a noob it could be much simpler.